# Recursive function throw StackOverflowError

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I am having problems with this function. I need to process more than 1 million records, but this crashes. Looks like just works with thousands of records and throws a StackOverflowError for a larger list. Any suggestions?

```
def split(list: List[(Pair, Boolean)]): List[List[Pair]] = list match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case head :: tail => {
    val (l1, l2) = tail.span(!_._2)
    (head :: l1).map(_._1) :: split(l2)
  }
}
```

Comment: If you need to process that amount of elements, I would suggest using some kind of stream. Maybe, **LazyList** would be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program will throw a StackOverflow exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:283)
```

The reason is very simple because your method is not tail-recursive
If you annotate it with @tailrec, it won't compile:

```
  @tailrec
  def split(list: List[(Pair, Boolean)]): List[List[Pair]] = list match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case head :: tail => {
      val (l1, l2) = tail.span(!_._2)
      (head :: l1).map(_._1) :: split(l2)
    }
  }
```

The solution is to make your recusion tailrec, or use some kind of loop instead

You could try something like this:

```
 @tailrec
  def split(list: List[(Pair, Boolean)], accumulator:  List[List[Pair]] = List[List[Pair]]()): List[List[Pair]] = list match {
    case Nil => accumulator
    case head :: tail => {
      val (l1, l2) = tail.span(!_._2)
      split(l2, (head :: l1).map(_._1)::accumulator)
    }
  }
```

Comment: So any example of the answer?

Comment: object Tester extends App {

  @tailrec
  def split(list: List[(Int, Boolean)], accumulator:  List[List[Int]] = List[List[Int]]()): List[List[Int]] = list match {
    case Nil => accumulator
    case head :: tail => {
      val (l1, l2) = tail.span(!_._2)
      split(l2, (head :: l1).map(_._1)::accumulator)
    }
  }

  split(List.fill(5000)(1,true))

}

Comment: just copy-paste the code of my last comment, I just replaced Pair by Int as I don't know what is Pair in your case

Comment: also add the annotation @tailrec to make sure your recursion is OK